# How to send form values to an email with out having any database and any server installed on hosting server

Tags: javascript, html, email

I have a website. I want to send the form values (which the visitor to my website enters) to my email id. I tried adding mailto: but when I click on Submit button it is asking to login from the options gmail, or yahoo e.t.c.

How do I allow the user of my website to send the form values to my mail id as soon as he clicks on sumbit button.

My application does not have a database or tomcat server installed. Directly I am uploading the HTML pages in the hosting server. There is no use of java, only html and javascript.
 Both the sender and receiver can be my own email id.

The thing is I want the form values sent to my email (using only html and javascript).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: <form action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain"> (from w3school)
Can you show us your code snippet?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. We help you with problems you already started with, thus we want to help you if you show us any code and show us what you have tried. Thats how this website work. I do can tell you, you can do this via `HTML` and the use of the `JavaScript`

Comment: Try here [Tutorial on how to use javascript to send a mail](http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/87504.aspx)

Comment: I did the same thing action="mailto:" but when I click on Submit button it asking me to login from say yahoo or gmail. May be to add sender's email Id.  I want both sender and receiver mail id to be my mail id

Comment: how to add the sender's email id in html/javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is no possible to send an email directly from JavaScript. With `mailto:` it will always open a window which the user must confirm first and then send it via user's email program. However [here](https://medium.com/@mariusc23/send-an-email-using-only-javascript-b53319616782) you can read how to get access to an API with which you can communicate just from JavaScript (JQuery ideally) and it will then send the emails for you.

Comment: I dont want the visitor to login. I want directly mail to be sent. How to add the sender's mail id i.e my own email id in html/javascript?

Comment: Yeah I know. That is what you do with the tutorial I sent you. You get access to the API and then your web app can use it to send emails without the uses confirming or do anything. Follow the link in my answer